# NodeMCU Lua bme280: float values on integer build?

Tags: lua, nodemcu

How can I get float values from a BME280 on a integer build using the BME280 Lua module with bme280_math?

Using the deprecated bme280 c-Module, for instance, temperature values were: temperature in °C * 100, getting float values was like:

`tempFloat = tostring(temp/100).."."..temp%100`

Now, with bme280 Lua module and bme280_math, the temperature is returned in °C, so on an integer build readings are now "24" instead of "24378". How to get "24378" again?

Comment: `tempFloat = tostring(temp)`?

Comment: It's an int. 
Was: 24378 with c-module on integer build
Is now: 24 with lua-module on integer build
When i convert the latter, "24.0" ist as goog as it gets. When I calculate from "24378" i get "24.378".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bme280 lua module used on an integer build will return integer values with 1°C resolution only.